# How to change value in asp Label using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have create a function `onchange` when there a textbox value change. I able to show the result into label using `innerHTML` using Javascript. But when come to code behind, ASP.Net VB is not able to get the label.text value. Is there any way to show the result in this label?

```html
<asp:Label ID="lblreserve1" runat="server" text="**HERE**" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" name="reservation-time" id="reservation-time" class="form-control" value="01/01/2016 - 01/25/2016" onchange="myFunction1(this.value)"/>
```

```js
function myFunction1(reservedate) {
  var x = document.getElementById("reservation-time").value;
  document.getElementById("<% =lblreserve1.clientID %>").innerText = x;
}
```

```vb
MsgBox(lblreserve1.Text)
```

Comment: The text of labels is not sent to the server. To do what you require you could put the required value in another hidden input

Comment: the problem is the value will also change time to time. or any way to get <label>value</label> value within span ?

Comment: You can put the value in whatever element you like, but if you want the server to be able to read it, then you need to include it in the request when the form is submit. To do that it needs to be placed in a form element, or added to the request payload manually if you're using AJAX.

Comment: im using vb.net is that possible using another way?

Comment: No. The language you're using is irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Do  you have sample? cuz im not familiar with AJAX

Comment: There's thousands if you Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an XY problem.  I don't think you want to change that label.

I imagine you have a textbox that is serving double duty.  If the label says one thing, the textbox contains data that means one thing; if the label says something else, the textbox contains some other data.  This is a really unusual way to accomplish what is a very common web UX.

Instead, create a series of label/textbox pairs and enclose them in DIV elements.  Hide all DIVs but one of them.  When you wish to "change" the label, unhide the DIV containing the label/textbox you want, and hide everything else.

When the form posts back to the server, all three textboxes will post back too.  The server can tell which label was shown because its textbox will contain a value.  Thus the server can infer the value of the label that was being shown when the form was submitted.

Comment: yea, but it still value empty. i found some source in the internet that using  Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lblreserve1") it not working...

Comment: You would use that sort of code if you were trying to write code to read a page from the client end, e.g. if you were screenscraping.  Is that what you are trying to do?